# phonegap data:image not displaying a image on certain android versions

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, samsung-mobile

I have standard code to capture and show a photo in a phonegap app

```
$scope.mobilePic = function () {
  var options = {
    quality: 75,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    allowEdit: true,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetWidth: 300,
    targetHeight: 300,
    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
  };

  $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
    $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
  }, function (err) {
    // An error occured. Show a message to the user
  });
};
```

My problem is that this code works well on my Samsung SM-T531 tablets that have an android version >5, however if I run the app with my Samsung SM-T330 that have android 4.4.2 the image is not displayed at all, the data is correctly captured though. Easy solution I think would be to upgrade the android version of my tablets but it doesn't seem to be available yet, I keep on clicking the software update button but everything is up to date. So quite stuck at the moment.

Any ideas?

Comment: So I've solved my problem by manually installing android lollipop on my devices from http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/confirm/50095/T330KXU1BOF8_T330KOO1BOF8_KOO/. It seems that there is clearly an issue with the webview for the android 4 for the image display, so not sure still how to resolve that without the upgrade

Comment: In my case, its related to System WebView Updates. Once I uninstall it, the images start working again, even in a Lollipop. It's not a solution, it's just the pointing to the guilty.